# Extra answers after an identification question has been correctly answered

Tags: discussion, story-identification

Suppose a story identification question (such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/what-short-story-interprets-common-idioms-literally)) has been satisfactorily answered.

Is it a good idea to propose another *very good* match for the question?

Should the question be treated as a list question, allowing answers that only have a thin link with the question?

How bad can a match be before the answer deserves a downvote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I'm the principle downvoter here. Where a question has already had an answer accepted, I have a simple criterion: is it plausible to assume that the person posting the new answer genuinely thinks the accepted answer is wrong or incomplete. If not, then I don't see what a suggestion of other works that are a bit like the work that's being looked for, but aren't actually it, can add to answering the question.

Comment: Without having given it a TON of though, I think disagree with you, here - it serves a secondary purpose in that people who are looking for a similar book that land on the "answered" question can see a list of other possible responses. There is value in that, to me.

Comment: I think that would be a better use of comments rather than answers though.  The "similar book suggestion" isn't an answer to the question so shouldn't be posted as one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this other [answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/247/28516) but wanted to say more than would fit in a comment.

Note other meta questions on this topic closed as duplicates:

- [Answering story-identification questions after OP has accepted an answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/answering-story-identification-questions-after-op-has-accepted-an-answer)
- [Story-ID answers after an accepted one? Are they useful?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13233/story-id-answers-after-an-accepted-one-are-they-useful)

Quoting from the accepted answer to the SE meta question [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question):

> - Be accurate and correct

Unless you think the accepted answer is wrong, an additional answer to a question like this is not "correct". Hopefully we can agree that story id questions have a correct answer.

> - Actually answer the question. Do not post an answer stating you have the same problem or one which only answers a question different from the one that was asked.

Writing an answer to a question when you know the answer is incorrect violates this principle.